# How to use calendar view to show particular date as free or busy for someone(Android)

Tags: android, android-layout

i have list of date for which user is not available from back end.but i am unable to put this date in calendar in which red symbol indicate busy and green symbol indicate free.Hope you understand what i'm trying to get.How can i achieved this in Android.
Any help will be Appreciated in advance..

Comment: Check out 'Extended CalendarView' https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView. It's pretty customizable and should do what you asked.

Comment: i have data in json format from backend about date and busy or free information

Comment: Can anyone Help me out by giving answer to this Question in details or give links as i'm new in android

Comment: Did you look at the  Github repository for ExtendedCalendarView like I suggested? With some configuring it will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`ExtendedCalendarView` should do this. Taken from the usage on [ExtendedCalendarView's GitHub repository](https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView):

1. Declare it in your layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.ExtendedCalendarView 
    android:id="@+id/calendar"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

2. Get the view like you normally would

```
ExtendedCalendarView calendar = (ExtendedCalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendar);
```

3. Declare the content provider in your manifest

```
<provider
    android:name="com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.CalendarProvider"
    android:authorities="com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.calendarprovider" 
/>
```

4. Add events to the calendar using the following procedure:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(CalendarProvider.COLOR, Event.COLOR_RED);
values.put(CalendarProvider.DESCRIPTION, "Some Description");
values.put(CalendarProvider.LOCATION, "Some location);
values.put(CalendarProvider.EVENT, "Event name);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

cal.set(startDayYear, startDayMonth, startDayDay, startTimeHour, startTimeMin);
values.put(CalendarProvider.START, cal.getTimeInMillis());
values.put(CalendarProvider.START_DAY, julianDay);
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();

cal.set(endDayYear, endDayMonth, endDayDay, endTimeHour, endTimeMin);
int endDayJulian = Time.getJulianDay(cal.getTimeInMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(tz.getOffset(cal.getTimeInMillis())));

values.put(CalendarProvider.END, cal.getTimeInMillis());
values.put(CalendarProvider.END_DAY, endDayJulian);

Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(CalendarProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Comment: sir ,After adding jar file, it gives layout exception ,can u help me in this regards..